# Unresolved overloaded function type in std::transfrom

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, overloading, std

I am trying to write an overload function for both `double` and `vector<double>`.

I just did the following:

```cpp
constexpr double degrees(double val) { return v * M_1_PI * 180.0; }

std::vector<double> degrees(const std::vector<double>& val)
{
    std::vector<double> out;
    out.reserve(val.size());
    std::transform(val.begin(), val.end(), std::back_inserter(out), degrees);
    return out;
}
```

I expect this to be rather straightforward, but it does not compile, and I cannot figure it out. The compiler cannot resolve the overloaded `degrees` function, and keeps complaining

```
couldn't deduce template parameter '_UnaryOperation'
```

---

Edit: fix the part with `reserve`, it is an obvious mistake.

Comment: You have two functions with the same name, `degrees`, and both taking a single argument. Which one of them should the compiler select? It can't decide by itself. I suggest you skip the first function and use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead.

Comment: You should use *either* a vector of specific size, *or* use `back_inserter`. Not both. Since you use both, you will get a `out` vector of size `val.size() * 2`, where the first half of `out` being all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to believe that the asker didn't know they are defining two functions with the same name `degrees`, so I'll give another shade to my answer.

*How is it possible, in this call*

```cpp
std::transform(val.begin(), val.end(), std::back_inserter(out), degrees);
```

*that `degrees` is not known? I mean, `std::transform` should try to apply `degrees` to each element in `val`, and since each of those elements is a `double`, isn't it obvious that transform should make use of the first overload, the one which takes a `double`?*

As convincing as this motivation might be, though, it would require the compiler to delay/defer the decision of what `degrees` should be called to the moment it's actually called, i.e. not at the call site of `std::transform`, but *inside* `std::transform` (specifically, when evaluating the expression `unary_op(*first1++)` in [this possible implementation on the cppreference doc page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform#Possible_implementation)).

This is simply not possible, as the rules are that the compiler must know at the call site of a function what its arguments are. With reference to the example, at the call site of `std::transform` the compiler has no idea which of the overloads of `degree` is needed.

One way around is to wrap `degrees` in a function object with overloaded `operator()`, as suggested by [463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69220069/5825294); doing so, the *object* `degrees` would be known at `std::transform` call site, and only *inside* `std::transform`, at the call site of the object's `operator()` would the compiler have to choose between the overloads of `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which overload should be passed to `std::transform`. E.g.

```
std::vector<double> degrees(const std::vector<double>& val) {
    std::vector<double> out;
    out.reserve(val.size());
    std::transform(val.begin(), val.end(), std::back_inserter(out), static_cast<double(*)(double)>(degrees));
    //                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return out;
}
```

BTW: `std::vector<double> out(val.size());` would construct `out` as containing `val.size()` elements with value `0.0`. I suppose this is not what you want. Default-initialization and `reserve` would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two issues

1. There are two functions overloads from which compiler can not  choose it automatically, which one to use. So you need to explicitly specify which one is to pass to the `std::transform`.
2. The `std::vector<double> out(val.size());` will create a vector of double with size `val.size()` and all the elements will be initiated with `0.0`. The `std::back_inserter(out)` then add element after these. Presumably, you do not want to have `val.size()` number of `0.0`s in the `out` vector, prior to the actual elements. You need a [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) there, for unwanted real locations.

That being said, I would suggest having a lambda function instead of a free function, which has the advantage of having the implementation of the function right into the place where it is called:

```
std::vector<double> degrees(const std::vector<double>& val)
{
    std::vector<double> out;
    out.reserve(val.size()); // reserve some memory
    std::transform(val.begin(), val.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
        [](double ele) {return ele * M_1_PI * 180.0; }
    );
    return out;
}
```

[See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wzedfed5s)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an overload set around, but you can pass a functor with overloaded call operator:

```
struct degrees {
    constexpr double operator()(double val) {return val * 0.3 * 180.0;}

    std::vector<double> operator()(const std::vector<double>& val) {
        std::vector<double> out(val.size());
        std::transform(val.begin(), val.end(), std::back_inserter(out), degrees{});
        return out;
    }
};
```